# Laravel Queues getting failed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-queue

I'm stuck in Laravel queues.. I'm doing evrything according to the documentation, but every time, the queued job is going into failed-job table.

I'm trying to queue a job that will import a csv file into the database.

In .env file I have done QUEUE_DRIVER=database. (P.S I'm using database for my queues, on my localhost, I'm using PHP version 5.5.3 on my mac). Jobs are getting created in database, but it is getting failed.

Code in my controller-

```
if($request->hasFile('import_file')){
            $country = MemberProfile::where('username',$username)->first(['country']);
            $csvname = $username.".".$request->file('import_file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $csvpath = base_path() . '/public/assets/memberCollection/';
            $request->file('import_file')->move($csvpath, $csvname);
            $data = new importDataJob;
            $data->path = $csvpath."".$csvname;
            $data->listindex = $listindex;
            $data->country = $country->country;
            $data->username = $username;
            $data->save();
            $this->dispatch(new ImportLeads($data));


        }
```

And the code in ImportLead.php Job file is this -

```
protected $impStuff;
/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(importDataJob $values)
{

    $this->impStuff = $values;
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    try{
        $data = Excel::load($this->impStuff->path, function($reader) {
        })->get();
        Storage::disk('local')->append('logtest.txt', $this->impStuff->path);
        //Inserting record by record into database
        if(!empty($data) && $data->count()){
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $member = new MemberController();
                //dd($this->impStuff["country"]);
                $number = $member->E164FormatNumber($value->mobile,$this->impStuff->country);
                $leadlistassoc_insert[] = ['listindex' => $this->impStuff->listindex, 'leadindex' => DB::table('leads')->insertGetId(['firstName' => $value->firstname, 'lastName' => $value->lastName, 'mobile' => $number, 'username' => $this->impStuff->username, 'created_at' => Carbon::now(), 'category' => 1])];

            }
            if(!empty($leadlistassoc_insert)){
                DB::table('leadlistassoc')->insert($leadlistassoc_insert);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        Storage::disk('local')->append('logtest.txt', $e);
    }
}

public function failed()
{
    Storage::disk('local')->append('logtest.txt', "failed");
}
```

The same code works if I place in in a different class, and call it's handle function manually.

Using Laravel 5.2 command to listen to database:

```
php artisan queue:listen --tries=3
```

Comment: Please share the error details

Comment: And share your queue configuration + .env file

Comment: @KhanShahrukh when artisan is listening to my database with `php artisan queue:listen` it is getting timed out saying `[Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException]               
  The process "'/usr/bin/php' 'artisan' queue:work '' --queue='default' --del  
  ay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=3 --tries=3 --env='local'" exceeded the timeout o  
  f 60 seconds. ` 

but when I run it as `php artisan queue:listen --tries=3` it is going into failed_jobs table saying `Failed: App\Jobs\ImportLeads`

Comment: @ArtyomSokolov my .env file is

`APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:PjkY1YNnfILbaY4eu0qWdT6zuFMD1/YepgseAvq1PLI=
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=typdb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=database

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379`

What is queue configuration..??

Comment: APP_FOLDER/config/queue.php

Comment: @ArtyomSokolov `return [

    'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'sync'),

    'connections' => [

        'sync' => [
            'driver' => 'sync',
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],

    ],

    'failed' => [
        'database' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
        'table' => 'failed_jobs',
    ],

];`

Comment: @ArtyomSokolov can you help..??

Comment: Do you test it with small file? I understand that you upload some kind of lead data to be imported. What will happen if you set --timeout=180 for queue listener?